# Mac: Installing app from Internet has an exception

Tags: macos, installation

I want to install Firefox in my MacBook, downloaded from Internet.

After a series of clicking, I can use it with an exception.

It is not in the LaunchPad. Looks like it is installed on an other disk.

Here is image:

[image: 000]

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you drag it to the Applications folder (as the green arrow suggests), and then run it from that folder rather than from the disk image?

Comment: Yes. Your tip solves me from months troubling. I used not to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag it to the Applications folder (as the green arrow suggests), and then run it from that folder rather than from the disk image.